# Sharing data between controllers, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing the following situation in my Angular application and I would like to have some advices here.

I have a page where I show some products, this page is managed by a controller called 'ProductsController'. This controller has a method called 'showProductDetails' which is called once the user clicks on a specific product, and the goal of this method is just to retrieve the details of the product and to display these details in a modal panel. 
Nothing really special until here. The problem is that because of modularity I would like to attach a different controller to the modal panel, and to manage all the logic of this modal panel in the new controller, in this case 'ProductDetailController'. The problem is that I retrieve the data of the product before opening the modal panel, but as I retrieve this data in the scope of the first controller, from the second controller I cannot access to the product that I have previously retrieved. I've been told that to share data between controllers in angularJs is done through services, but I don't see how a stateless service can help me here.

Here is my code to understand better the situation:

The first controller:

```
app.controller('ProductsController', ['$scope','productsFactory','commonFactory','productsFactoryHelper','$filter','$modal',function ($scope,productsFactory,commonFactory,productsFactoryHelper,$filter,$modal)
                               {




$scope.showProductDetails = function (size,product) {

$scope.showLoader('Loading the details of the product. Please wait...');

productsFactoryHelper.Product.query({id:product.id},function(response)
    {
    $scope.selectedProduct=response;
    $scope.hideLoader();
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'productDetail.html',
          controller: 'ProductDetailController',
          size: size

        });
    },function(error)
    {
    commonFactory.Pop('error','This product is not available at this moment.  Please try again later. If the problem persists contact a system administrator');
                    $scope.hideLoader();
    });


};

_init();    
                               }]);
```

And the second controller:

```
app.controller('ProductDetailController',['$scope','$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

                                 $scope.ok = function () {
                                   $modalInstance.close();
                                 };

                                 $scope.cancel = function () {
                                   $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                                 };
                               }]);
```

So basically the question is how can access from the 'ProductDetailController' to the object 'selectedProduct' which is in the scope of the 'ProductsController'.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you make controller with selectedProduct a service and attach $watch to the variable? And inject the service in two controllers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular: Share data between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use resolve of the $modal to send your data to the new controller like below.

```
app.controller('ProductsController', ['$scope','productsFactory','commonFactory','productsFactoryHelper','$filter','$modal',function ($scope,productsFactory,commonFactory,productsFactoryHelper,$filter,$modal)
                                      {




    $scope.showProductDetails = function (size,product) {

        $scope.showLoader('Loading the details of the product. Please wait...');

        productsFactoryHelper.Product.query({id:product.id},function(response)
                {
            $scope.selectedProduct=response;
            $scope.hideLoader();
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'productDetail.html',
                controller: 'ProductDetailController',
                size: size,
                resolve:{
                    "selectedProduct":response
                }

            });
                },function(error)
                {
                    commonFactory.Pop('error','This product is not available at this moment.  Please try again later. If the problem persists contact a system administrator');
                    $scope.hideLoader();
                });


    };

    _init();    
                                      }]);
```

I dont know about the producfactory helper product query has a promise if it has a promise you can use like this..

```
$scope.showProductDetails = function (size,product) {

    $scope.showLoader('Loading the details of the product. Please wait...');

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'productDetail.html',
        controller: 'ProductDetailController',
        size: size,
        resolve:{
            "selectedProduct":productsFactoryHelper.Product.query({id:product.id})
        }
    });
};
```

And in the ProductDetailController you can inject this selectedProduct like below

```
app.controller('ProductDetailController',['$scope','$modalInstance','selectedProduct ' function ($scope, $modalInstance,selectedProduct ) {

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can indeed be done through services, since they are stateless and keep their data once instantiated.

```
function productService($http) {

    this.products = [];

    this.loadProducts() {
        $http.get('/url/to/your/product/api').then(function(err, data) {    
            this.products = data.products;
        });
    };

    this.getProducts = function() {
        return this.products;
    }
}

angular
    .module('yourModule')
    .service('productService', productService);
```

You can then just inject `productService` in both controllers, load the products using `productService.loadProducts()`, and get them using `productService.getProducts()`.

This is just an example. Services can be used to share any kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Services are indeed the answer for you, or you can use pure eventing if you do not need to access the data more then once.

Pure Eventing

```
app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope) {
    // Do something

    // Action completed
    @scope.$emit('someactionComplete', data);
});

app.controller('childCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('someactionComplete', function(data) {
        // Process data
    });
});
```

Using a service. The advantage of using a service is that the data is persisted.

```
app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    // Do something

    // Action completed
    MyService.setData(data);
    @scope.$emit('someactionComplete');
});

app.controller('childCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('someactionComplete', function() {
        MyService.getData(data);
    });
});
```

You could further enhance this were the service loaded the data and returns a promise in the getter.